# What is the error in this sample code via scipy docs that attempts to solve an ode?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, documentation, runtime-error, ode

I am trying to learn about solving ODEs in python and scipy seemed like a good starting point. I've become comfortable with using `odeint` and am now trying to learn how to use `ode`. I tried running the sample code in the [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html), but it is returning an error. I've copied the code below alongside the error.

CODE

```
from scipy.integrate import ode

y0, t0 = [1.0j, 2.0], 0

def f(t, y, arg1):
    return [1j*arg1*y[0] + y[1], -arg1*y[1]**2]

def jac(t, y, arg1):
    return [[1j*arg1, 1], [0, -arg1*2*y[1]]]

r = ode(f, jac).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf', with_jacobian=True)
r.set_initial_value(y0, t0).set_f_params(2.0).set_jac_params(2.0)
t1 = 10
dt = 1

while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    print("%g %g" % (r.t, r.y))
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
    print("%g %g" % (r.t, r.y))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r.y` is a length 2 array. And that of complex numbers. Both is incompatible with the formatting instruction for one float.

Implicit conversion to string however works,

```
    print "%g %s" % (r.t, r.y)
```